# How can I know what the latest Yammer message using the REST Api?

Tags: rest, yammer

I have a client that get all company messages and according to the documentation we should use this call, where latestid is a number like : 792425364

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?newer_than=<latestid>
```

When I inspect the results I get:

1. Not only messages but also other entries
2. Messages, but I cannot see any order

So I guess I am looking for a sample that first fetches "all" messages (without the newer_than parameter) and in a second iteration uses the "latest" id from the previously retrieved list.

Comment: Use Slack and never worry about it =P

Comment: Which programming language are you using to do this? Post a sample of results you are getting and what you think you should be getting. Post some code as well.

Comment: @GouravChawla I am using java and I get the same results as with the https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesjson TryItOut method. I will post my results as an edit of the original question.

Comment: While editing out some of the repetitive entries, I came across a JSONArray called messages. They seem to be ordered ... To be continued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GouravChawla I was forced to take a closer look.

The JSON that is return by the endpoint

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json
```

Contains a "messages" property.
The messages in this array are ordered by id, at least so it appears at first look.

When I use

```
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json?newer_than=<latestid>;
```

And provide the message id of the first entry of the first call, I get zero results.
If I provide the message id of the second entry I get one result, that is the one with the message id of the first entry of the first call.